# How Can I Run a legacy Classic ASP Site with Cybercash on 64 bit Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: asp-classic, windows-server-2008-r2, credit-card, legacy

I have a classic ASP site running on old hardware and Windows 2000.  I need to migrate it to new hardware running Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit.  In particular, I need to reinstall the ancient Cybercash credit card clearing software.  I have the Merchant Kit download,
but when I try to run mck-3.2.0.4-nt.exe, it won't run because it is a 16 bit app.  How can I get around this roadblock?

Comment: There's no newer version of the software? Or at least a 32-bit edition of that version?

Comment: 64 bit windows supports 32 bit software, 32 bit supports 16 bit but 64 bit doesn't support 16 bit, sorry. Anyway, a server setup which processes credit card payments needs to be PCI compliant and that might be difficult using obsolete software.  Would you trust your system with your own credit cards?

Comment: John, PCI compliance is one of the reasons for this migration.  The compliance test strongly objected to IIS 5 and Windows 2000.  First step is to move to new IIS and server software, then rerun the test.  The PCI tests seem to be ignorant of the fact that these old systems could be pretty well locked down, which this one was.  The actual clearance code was not faulted in the tests.  At this stage it's a matter of getting the existing code (very extensive) to run.

Answer (score 1):

I posted this question so I could answer it, because I just had to do this, and I thought the answers may be of interest to others.
According to a techie at Paypal, many tens of thousands of sites still run Cybercash.  So others may be doing a migration like mine.

The trick here is to recognize that the mck-3.2.0.4-nt.exe program is the unzip program.  It was run on the Windows 2000 Server,
creating everything you need in a directory c:\mck-3.2.0.4-nt.  For classic ASP all you need are the four files under
c:\mck-3.2.0.4-nt\asp-api. It may have been unzipped elsewhere, but you should be able to find it and copy it to your new server.

There are 4 include files: CCMckDirectLib.inc,CCMckLib.inc, CCMsw.inc, and CCVarBlock.inc
and a subdirectory cychmck.  The include files should have been copied into what ever directory that contains the
credit card clearing ASP page. If you copied the website files properly from the old server to the new server, they should be there.

Now all you have to do is install the active X component, which is the cychmck.dll in the cychmck directory.
To run classic ASP on IIS 7+ you need to have your app pool set up to run 32 bit applications. So you need to install
the dll with a command line that looks like this:

\windows\syswow64\regsvr32 /s cychmck.dll

Once cybercash is installed, the credit card clearing ASP page should run on the new server just like it did on the old server.

No one likes to use old software for new projects, but code that works and has run for years is hard to beat. Sometimes
we can teach a new do old tricks :)

I appreciate this resource: http://winsupport.org/cybercash.html

Comment: Classic ASP will run in a 64 bit app pool on IIS7, but a lot of components you're likely to use are available only as 32 bit - most notably the OLEDB JET database driver (to connect to Access), so practically speaking you will indeed need to enable 32 bit applications in a Classic ASP site.  Thanks for posting this.  Apart from the specific information it's quite useful to know that 32 bit dlls live in Syswow64.  It also contains a 32 bit version of the ODBC Data Source Administrator which I didn't know about until I'd had Win7 for 6 months.  You can only find the 64 bit one in Control Panel.